# explanation on usign : in a for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

can anyone explain what does it means when you write `for(a:b)` instead of the normally `for(int i =0; i < a; i++)`. A and b are both variables.

What has a and b in comments?

Here is an example where : is used in a for-loop;

```
for(PersonalRegistrationData personalRegistrationData : personalRegistrationDataList) {
        if (personalRegistrationData.getEmployeeInitials().equalsIgnoreCase(employeeInitials) &&
                personalRegistrationData.getPersonalActivityID() == personalActivityID && personalRegistrationData.getWeekNumber() == weekNumber) {
            return personalRegistrationData;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your example isn't javascript

Comment: looks Java to me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Java 'for each' loop work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work)

Answer (score 0):

The loop: `for(int i =0; i < a; i++)` is just a classic loop, loop a times to do some things.
The loop: `for(a: b)` (this is the foreach loop in Java) is a loop through a element of a collection. In your example: `for(PersonalRegistrationData personalRegistrationData : personalRegistrationDataList)` the `personalRegistrationData` is a collection of `PersonalRegistrationData` and the `personalRegistrationData` is an element inside your collection. This loop is useful when you need to get an element from the collection instead of using the first loop with `personalRegistrationDataList.get(i)`